# tracking vehicle or phone location using google map

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
  <script>
  var map, infoWindow;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 6
    });
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;


    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  }

  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                          'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
    infoWindow.open(map);
  }

</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

I am designing a system with php, CodeIgniter and MySQL that will be used to track the current location of vehicle or mobile phone with details from MySQL database while its on the go, and I want it in a way that the marker points to the current position of the user and then move while the user moves.

I have tried the code above and I'm not satisfied with what I got.

Answer (score 1):

You will find a complete working example of what you are trying to do [here](https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen)

Sadly, as W3C/IETF simply refuse to acknowledge to background geolocation requirement you must keep your app in the foreground for it to work :-(

Comment: this is awesome. I

Comment: Won't be awesome until W3C starts allocating resources based on demand and technical merit :-(